# Difference between numpy.matrix.A1 and ravel

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

To my knowledge, I haven't seen any posts regrading this, if any, please note me.

According to [SciPy website](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.A1.html), `numpy.matrix.A1` is equivalent to `np.asarray(x).ravel()`.

> One example will be enough to illustrate the problem:
>
> ```
> x = np.matrix(np.arange(12).reshape((1, -1)))
>
>
> print("Shape of x: ", x.shape)
> print("Shape of x with asarray: ", np.asarray(x).shape)
> print("Equality: ", np.array_equal(x, np.asarray(x)))
> print("Shape of x ravel flatten: ", x.ravel().shape)
> print("Shape of x ravel flatten with asarray: ", np.asarray(x).ravel().shape)
> ```
>
> Prints:
>
> ```
> Shape of x:  (1, 12)
> Shape of x with asarray:  (1, 12)
> Equality:  True
> Shape of x ravel flatten:  (1, 12)
> Shape of x ravel flatten with asarray:  (12,)
> ```

**Problem:**

As observed, **the dimension of flattened array is different with `asarray`**, just wondered why it's being presenting such inconsistencies in dimensions?

From `np` implementation of `asarray` function, I didn't see any thing might cause a dimension problem, plus it passes the equality test (`x == np.asarray(x)`). But other than this, what could be possibly making implicit changes to the array.

```
def asarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
```

**Edited:**

This could be confusing

> plus it passes the equality test (`x == np.asarray(x)`)

to be more precise, I mean, it passes the equality test (`np.array_equal(x, np.asarray(x))`)

Comment: Strange it is.  np.matrix may be discontinued, so I wouldn't weave it into your projects if you can get around it.

Comment: I see. Is there any replacement for `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`, that's the reason I sticked with matrix. Is there something like a sparse tensor in Numpy?

Comment: The `A1` was provided to get around the fact that the `matrix.ravel()` is still 2d.

Comment: The scipy sparse module is not a subclass of `np.matrix`.  It's modeled in many ways on `np.matrix`, and some operations return a dense matrix.  But internally all sparse formats use `ndarrays` to store their attributes.  Dense arrays don't have to be converted to `np.matrix` to interact with sparse matrices.

Comment: I don't think the 2d matrix nature of the scipy sparse module will disappear or be replaced anytime soon.  It's baked into the code too deeply.  The underlying math was developed for linear algebra tasks.  MATLAB hasn't extended their sparse matrix code to work with higher dimensions (unlike their regular matrices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy matrices (`np.matrix`) are *always 2D*.  (Mathematically, the strict definition of a matrix, rather than a matrix or vector.)

From `np.matrix.ravel`:

> Return the matrix flattened to shape `(1, N)` where `N` is the number
>   of elements in the original matrix.

Some motivation for NumPy matrices is for Matlab users.  See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) for some of the finer points on NumPy `matrix` versus `array`.

In brief, a NumPy array (the result of `asarray(x)` here) can be a 1-dimensional structure.  Matrices can be a minimum of 2d.  `type(np.asarray(x))` is, not shockingly, an array.  (Not to be confused with [`np.asanyarray()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asanyarray.html), for which your result would be a matrix because it's an array subclass.

Lastly, you noted:

> it passes the equality test (`x == np.asarray(x)`)

I see how this could be a bit confusing.  Technically, you want to use `np.array_equal(x, np.asarray(x))`, although that still evaluates to `True`.  However, NumPy logic testing is generally meant to be *data-structure agnostic*, in general:

```
np.array_equal([1, 2, 3], np.array([1, 2, 3]))
# True
```

(Here is the [source for `array_equal()`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L2392)--both are cast to arrays.)

The bottom line is that their "minimum dimensionalities" are different, and one is a subclass of the other.

```
issubclass(np.matrix, np.ndarray)
# True
```