# Dynamic indexing of numpy 2D matrix with column matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D matrix that is, say, 4x3, i.e. 4 rows by 3 columns.

```
A = matrix([[1,2,3],
           [4,5,6],
           [7,8,9],
           [-1,-2,-3]])
```

I have also a column matrix that is 4x1:

```
M = matrix([[1],
            [1],
            [1],
            [0]])
```

I would like to be able to get all columns of A for M!=0, i.e. some thing like `B=A[M!=0,:]`. But I get **too many indices for array** error. I simply want to obtain:

```
B = matrix([[1,2,3],
            [4,5,6],
            [7,8,9]])
```

by removing the last row of `A` because the last row of `M` is 0. I'm sure it is easy but I cannot figure how to do this.

I'm using Numpy 1.11.2 on Python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: A = np.array([[1,2,3],
   ...:            [4,5,6],
   ...:            [7,8,9],
   ...:            [-1,-2,-3]])

In [2]: M = np.array([[1],
   ...:             [1],
   ...:             [1],
   ...:             [0]])
```

I switched to `np.array`, the prefer type.

```
In [3]: A[M,:]
Out[3]: 
array([[[4, 5, 6]],

       [[4, 5, 6]],

       [[4, 5, 6]],

       [[1, 2, 3]]])
In [4]: _.shape
Out[4]: (4, 1, 3)
```

Indexing with `M` directly produces wrong shape, and wrong rows - multiple copies of row 1, and one copy of row 0.

Now switch to boolean version of `M`:

```
In [5]: M>0
Out[5]: 
array([[ True],
       [ True],
       [ True],
       [False]])
In [6]: A[M>0,:]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call 
...
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Oops the (4,1) shape it biting us here.  So change `M` to 1d:

```
In [7]: M1 = M.ravel()
In [8]: A[M1>0,:]
Out[8]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

We could also use `where` to get the row indices:

```
In [9]: idx = np.where(M1)
In [10]: idx
Out[10]: (array([0, 1, 2]),)
In [11]: A[_,:]
Out[11]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]])
```

---

If `M` was the np.matrix`, we'd have to use`M.A1` to produce the 1d indexing array.

[Difference between numpy.matrix.A1 and ravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48981856/difference-between-numpy-matrix-a1-and-ravel)

```
In [13]: MM = np.matrix([[1],
    ...:             [1],
    ...:             [1],
    ...:             [0]])
    ...: 
    ...: 
In [14]: MM
Out[14]: 
matrix([[1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [0]])
In [15]: MM.ravel()
Out[15]: matrix([[1, 1, 1, 0]])
In [16]: A[MM.ravel()>0,:]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-2ee7cf5210f1> in <module>()
----> 1 A[MM.ravel()>0,:]

IndexError: too many indices for array
In [17]: MM.A1
Out[17]: array([1, 1, 1, 0])
In [18]: A[MM.A1>0,:]
Out[18]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas. This is right up its alley

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


A = np.array([[1,2,3],
   [4,5,6],
   [7,8,9],
   [-1,-2,-3]])

M = np.array([[1],
    [1],
    [1],
    [0]])

dfa = pd.DataFrame(A)
dfm = pd.DataFrame(M)
seriesm = (pd.Series(dfm[dfm.columns[0]]) != 0)
matrixYouWant = dfa[seriesm.values]
```

If you want it back to a numpy array:

```
yourNewArray = matrixYouWant.values
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I'd like to stitch to numpy without using any other package. Anyway, I'll take a look at pandas.

Comment: It's numpy on steroids. If you're modeling data in python. It's worth the learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution which works like this

```
A = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3], 
              [ 4,  5,  6],
              [ 7,  8,  9],
              [-1, -2, -3]])

M = np.array([[1],
              [1],
              [1],
              [0],])

>>> mask = np.concatenate(M).astype(bool)

>>> out = A[:, mask]

>>> print(out)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```